# Escape first = for a properties file's Map (ATG/Java)

Tags: java, properties, atg

Did you guys (ATG/Java) come across to escape first '=' for a properties file's Map?

I have one map in my properties file like this:

```
elementToPropertyMap=\
        ./Name/Value[@locale\='en']=displayName
```

Here, what I want first equal should ignore i.e

```
Key = ./Name/Value[@locale\='en'] and value = displayName
```

I tried these variations and but didn't get the required output.

```
1 ./Name/Value[@locale\='en']=displayName           ./Name/Value[@locale\
2 ./Name/Value[@locale\\='en']=displayName          ./Name/Value[@locale\\
3 ./Name/Value[@locale//='en']=displayName          ./Name/Value[@locale//
4 ./Name/Value[@locale\=\'en']=displayName          ./Name/Value[@locale\
5 ./Name/Value[@locale\\=\\'en']=displayName        ./Name/Value[@locale\\
6 ./Name/Value[@locale/\=/\'en']=displayName        ./Name/Value[@locale/\
7 ./Name/Value[@locale\u003d'en']=displayName       ./Name/Value[@locale\u003d'en']
```

Yes, we can you {0} and replace with ''=" or use unicode in properties and convert its value.

But wanted to know is there default way to escape **first equal.**

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: These are ATG related code. I want to know is there any way in ATG to escape first =

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it out - the other way around?
I took the key which has a backslash before the `=`. So that becomes `\\`.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("./Name/Value[@locale\\='en']", "displayName");
properties.setProperty("./Name/Value[@locale='en']", "displayName");
properties.store(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("test.properties")), "Test");
```

Gives a test.properties:

```
#Test
#Wed Jul 12 14:48:19 CEST 2017
./Name/Value[@locale\\\='en']=displayName
./Name/Value[@locale\='en']=displayName
```

The explanation is that `=` and the backslash itself, as part of the key must be escaped. (Also `:` would have need of escaping.) So two additional backslashes.

`\u003d` is the exactly the same as an equal sign and has no effect.